# Error with business manager owned_business endpoint: deprecation of role_based field permitted_role in v3.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the facebook business API to create a child business manager for a 3rd party page.

I've been following the documentation which gives the following as an example of how to create a child business manager.

```sh
curl \
  -F 'id=<Parent Business Manager Id>' \
  -F 'name=Advertisers child BM' \
  -F 'vertical=OTHER' \ // Specify the Business vertical
  -F 'shared_page_id=<PAGE_ID_FROM_USER>' \  //Optional parameter
  -F 'page_permitted_roles=["ADVERTISER"]' \
  -F 'timezone_id=1' \
  -F 'access_token=<CLIENTS_ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=<APP_SECRET>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<PARENT_BM_Id>/owned_businesses
```

Unfortunately, when I do this request I'm getting the following error:

> (#12) Deprecated role based field in two tier endpoints as of V3.3 is deprecated for versions v3.3 and higher

Which I'm assuming corresponds to the following from the v3.3 release notes:

> Deprecated the role_based field permitted_role in Business Manager API. The following endpoint is impacted: `POST {business-id}/owned_businesses.`

After seeing that I figured the best thing to do would be to simply remove page_permitted_roles from my request. Unfortunately, that resulted in the following error:

> The parameter `page_permitted_roles` or `page_permitted_tasks` is required when sharing page access

I figured maybe `ADVERTISER` was deprecated form page_permitted_roles, so I tried `ADMIN` instead, which resulted in the following error:

> Param page_permitted_roles[0] must be one of {MANAGER, CONTENT_CREATOR, MODERATOR, ADVERTISER, INSIGHTS_ANALYST}

which..... gets us right back where we started.

I'm fairly sure I'm using the right access_token, appsecret_proof, etc, but I suppose it's possible I'm not. I am using the access token from a login request with the business_manager scope though, which I think is right.

If anyone has any insight into this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can see the breaking change in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.3#bm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... the answer to this is a bit anticlimactic. I figured it out myself when I tried with a fresh head this morning.

This line was the hint:

> The parameter `page_permitted_roles` or `page_permitted_tasks` is required when sharing page access

It turns out that using `page_permitted_tasks` solves the problem. I'm now using

```
-F 'page_permitted_tasks=["ADVERTISE"]' \
```

which doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: I previously used `page_permitted_roles=["ADVERTISER"]` (which used to be in FB's examples and used to work). Had the same error as you. Changed to `page_permitted_tasks=["ADVERTISE"]` and looks like that fixed it.